# Chinese letters are not correct in JFreeChart (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: fonts, language-support, locale, internationalization

I am using JFreeChart in my web application. French, German languages are rendered without any issue. But when i use Chinese and Japanese locale the languages are rendered as square box. At the same time in Windows machine it works perfectly. I can't able to solve this issue. So please guide me.

Comment: Hi Friends.....Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The font is not supporting the full range of Unicode characters that you want to display, so use a different font.

http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116561

Comment: Hi David,Initially i used the font "Lucida Grande". I am facing the same issue after changing the different font. Please help me.